# Pulling through subquery calculations

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I having a bit of an issue with a subquery and was hoping to get some input.  I'm trying to aggregate data from two tables, I've gotten aggregation to work great from Financial Table (in isolation), but I'm having an issue on the claims piece.  It's turning everything Cartesian, so I tried to write the claims calculations in the second subquery, but the main query has problems referencing the fields states c.CLM_LN_PD_AMT does not exist.  This is the part before I moved the calculations into the second subquery.  (sum CLM_LN_PD in subquery and then call c.clm_ln_pd in main query.  Any nudge would be awesome.

```
select sum(f.MED_ELIGTY_IND) as MEDMEMBERMONTHS,
       sum(f.PHARM_ELIGTY_IND) as RXMONTHS,
       avg(f.DIAG_CD_RSK_SCORE) as MEDRISK,
       avg(f.DIAG_CD_PHARM_RSK_SCORE) as PHARMRISK,
       count(distinct c.CLM_ID_TXT) as NUMCLAIMS,
       sum(c.CLM_LN_PD_AMT) as PAIDAMT,
       sum(c.CLM_LN_ALWD_AMT) as ALWDAMT,
       f.ELIGTY_MO_YYYYMM,
       f.SE_NAME
  from (select CTG_ID_TXT,
               MED_ELIGTY_IND,
               PHARM_ELIGTY_IND,
               DIAG_CD_RSK_SCORE,
               DIAG_CD_PHARM_RSK_SCORE,
               ELIGTY_MO_YYYYMM,
               SE_NAME
          from FINCL_ATTRBN_RESLT_PMPM
         Where to_char(ELIGTY_AS_OF_DT, 'mm/dd/yyyy') = '02/20/2014'
           and ELIGTY_MO_YYYYMM between '201301' and '201312'
           and CNTRCT_TYP_ID = '331929495'
           and ACTRL_LOB not in ('BOEI', 'SC_ASO')) f,
       (select distinct (CTG_ID), CLM_ID_TXT, CLM_LN_PD_AMT, CLM_LN_ALWD_AMT
          from CLM_MED_DETL_VW
         where to_char(CLM_LN_SVC_FROM_DT, 'yyyymm') between '201301' and
               '201312'
           and CLM_MED_DETL_VW.PD_PRD_YYYYMM between '201301' and '201312'
           and CLM_MED_DETL_VW.CLM_ADJ_PRD_YYYYMM is null) c
 where c.CTG_ID = f.CTG_ID_TXT
 Group by f.SE_NAME, f.ELIGTY_MO_YYYYMM
 order by f.SE_NAME, f.ELIGTY_MO_YYYYMM
```

Comment: What are the field types in your id fields f.CTG_ID_TXT and c.CTG_ID.

Comment: I believe they are both var char.  I know the join works, but it gets cartesian.  I was thinking to in the 2nd subquery count CLM_ID_TXT, sum CLM_LN_PD_AMT, CLM_LN_ALWD_AMT (replicate the main query calculations for claims) in subquery c.  But for some reason it loses the reference to c.  Wonder if I would need to group by PD_PRD_YYYYMM and sum per member in the subquery.  Arg, I know it's closeish, but not quite right.

Comment: @user197240 Unless you add table schema, some sample data and desired output, your question falls to category: `Please someone use telepathy and tell me why it doesn't work`. Really how do you expect people without knowing table design and goal you want to achieve to answer your question?

Comment: I'm not as familiar with Oracle - have you tried writing the join like this:

Comment: INNER JOIN (select ...... is null) c ON f.CTG_ID_TXT = c.CTG_ID  In SQL Server, the items in the WHERE happen after the JOIN. Note that the comma is not needed when using this syntax. IF that works, maybe you can get rid of the sub query and just query the tables.